# Why does nativescript with firebase run fail?

Tags: ios, firebase, nativescript

Hy

i try to run my nativescript firebase on a real device. But i get the following error.

```
Webpack compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
Webpack build done!
nativescript-plugin-firebase: building for same environment, not forcing prepare.
Updating runtime package.json with configuration values...
Project successfully prepared (ios)
Building project...
Xcode build...
/Users/michael/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Notifier-evgqptqlgvcdmdeqgihzagdiotph/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Notifier/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Notifier.app/Frameworks/TKLiveSync.framework: errSecInternalComponent
Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code
/Users/michael/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Notifier-evgqptqlgvcdmdeqgihzagdiotph/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Notifier/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Notifier.app/Frameworks/NativeScript.framework: errSecInternalComponent
Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code
/Users/michael/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Notifier-evgqptqlgvcdmdeqgihzagdiotph/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Notifier/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Notifier.app/Frameworks/TNSWidgets.framework: replacing existing signature
/Users/michael/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Notifier-evgqptqlgvcdmdeqgihzagdiotph/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Notifier/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Notifier.app/Frameworks/TNSWidgets.framework: errSecInternalComponent
Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
```

If i open the platforms/iOS/Notifier.xcworkspace file with XCode an klick play the app starts ant the push notification works. Only if i execute the command 'tns run ios' i get the error

Pod version: 1.10.1

XCode version: 12.2

tns version: 7.1.2

Have anyone the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who encounters this, the answer is Apple's security and keychain.  Most likely, you are logging in via SSH, which does not unlock the keychain (or provide a popup).

Run this before your build: `security unlock-keychain login.keychain`

You can use the `-p [Password]` if you need it to login automatically.